# Google's HttpResponse crashes app when parsing as a user defined class

Tags: java, android, json, google-places-api, httpresponse

I am trying to build a simple search nearby business app using Google Places and Maps api. It is my first time using threads, http requests/response and parsing results. I've tried to integrate some of the code this gentleman has provided in his blog:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

but unfortunately the app crashes each and every time when attempting to parse a http response.

```
try {
            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory();
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
            request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
            if (types != null)
                request.getUrl().put("types", types);
            HttpResponse r = request.execute();


            if(r.getContent()==null){
                Log.e("GOOGLE PLACES:", "NULL!!!!!");
                return null;
            }else{
//                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(r.getContent());
//                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
//
//                String readed;
//                while ((readed = in.readLine()) != null) {
//                    System.out.println(readed);
//                }
                PlacesList list = r.parseAs(PlacesList.class);
                return list;

            }

//            PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
//            Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
//            return list;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
```

When I print out the string to the console, it prints out fine but otherwise it crashes immediately so I'm not sure where I got the code wrong.

PlaceList.class:

```
public class PlacesList implements Serializable {

    @Key
    public String status;

    @Key
    public List<Place> results;

}
```

Place.class:

```
public class Place implements Serializable {

    @Key
    public String id;

    @Key
    public String name;

    @Key
    public String reference;

    @Key
    public String icon;

    @Key
    public String vicinity;

    @Key
    public Geometry geometry;

    @Key
    public String formatted_address;

    @Key
    public String formatted_phone_number;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " - " + id + " - " + reference;
    }

    public static class Geometry implements Serializable
    {
        @Key
        public Location location;
    }

    public static class Location implements Serializable
    {
        @Key
        public double lat;

        @Key
        public double lng;
    }

}
```

My coordinates are fine, the API_KEY is working now (took a while to figure I was using the wrong one... thought for sure I figured it out after I fixed that).

Not sure if this will help or not but here is the Async class as well:

```
class LoadList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();
            try{
                placesList = googlePlaces.search(latitude,longitude,1000,"cafe");

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
...
```

I said it crashes when parsing as a user defined class because the debugger can't get past that line `PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);` If I only execute the response and get the content and print it out then it runs fine.

A little chunk of the log:

```
A/art: art/runtime/quick_exception_handler.cc:433] Check failed: result 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] Runtime aborting...
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] Aborting thread:
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] "AsyncTask #2" prio=4 tid=17 Runnable
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cbc430 self=0x716f73819200
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | sysTid=8924 nice=10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x716f608fa450
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=273 stm=3 core=0 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | stack=0x716f607f8000-0x716f607fa000 stackSize=1037KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #00 pc 000000000052c46e  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+238)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #01 pc 00000000004fd3dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+412)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #02 pc 00000000004ea3bb  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+43)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #03 pc 00000000004ea122  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+274)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #04 pc 00000000004dd11d  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+125)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #05 pc 000000000014bd28  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD1Ev+1240)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #06 pc 00000000004d19ed  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art22DeoptimizeStackVisitor30HandleOptimizingDeoptimizationEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPKb+701)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #07 pc 00000000004d16a4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art22DeoptimizeStackVisitor10VisitFrameEv+852)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #08 pc 00000000004f1b68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12StackVisitor9WalkStackEb+680)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #09 pc 00000000004d079c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art21QuickExceptionHandler15DeoptimizeStackEv+108)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #10 pc 0000000000507388  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread21QuickDeliverExceptionEv+968)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #11 pc 0000000000609ba3  /system/lib64/libart.so (artThrowNullPointerExceptionFromCode+131)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #12 pc 0000000000136641  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_throw_null_pointer_exception+81)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #13 pc 0000000000010636  /data/data/edu.depaul.csc472.coffeeshoplocator/cache/slice-google-http-client-1.22.0_0f5b4fc19775565005c863a3f1ee7fd20d1a3454-classes.dex (Java_com_google_api_client_http_HttpResponse_parseAs__Ljava_lang_Class_2+146)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at edu.depaul.csc472.coffeeshoplocator.GooglePlaces.search(GooglePlaces.java:50)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at edu.depaul.csc472.coffeeshoplocator.ListActivity$LoadList.doInBackground(ListActivity.java:61)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at edu.depaul.csc472.coffeeshoplocator.ListActivity$LoadList.doInBackground(ListActivity.java:55)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock
```

Comment: `request.execute().parseAs`... This is not how you use AsyncTask

Comment: Sorry it's not clear from the code. Async is in the main activity, it performs the search in a separate class, that is GooglePlaces.class.

Comment: Okay, maybe I misunderstood. You should [edit] your post to include the logcat. It is not clear what crashes your app

Comment: I tried but the output was over the limit of what is allowed in a post. It's very long...I'll post a condensed version maybe that'll help?

Comment: At least the lines that have `Caused by` and the few lines that follow

Comment: Updated! Does that help?

Comment: Hmm. Not really. All I can tell is that that tutorial is 4 years old, and that there is an actual Google Places API now, so there should be no need to make HTTP requests directly like that. https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/

Comment: I definetely understand that it is outdated. However the search part still seems relevant: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: Sure. The API still works. I was just pointing you at the Android API, in case you decided to use that instead of parsing out some HTTP requests yourself. I am not sure how that `HttpRequest` class works, or its `parseAs` method